# AJAX post call to node.js server route - providing Cross origin request error

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I am new to node.js and trying to use my basic API and call the correct router.get function in my route file.

I have a basic clientside javascript for the ajax post:

```
console.log("main.js loaded");

var form = document.getElementById('addUserForm');
form.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('username', username);

  window.ajaxCall.call("POST", "localhost:3000/api/users/add", fd, function(responseText){
    // var response = JSON.parse(responseText);
    console.log(response);
  });
});
```

In this client side javascript I am using a custom xmlhttprequest library - I will provide the code below the whole question ( maybe the error for node js is there )

** UPDATE ** When I change the ajax call url to : /api/users/add or http://localhost:3000/api/users/add I get the following error : `POST http://localhost:3000/api/users/add 404 (Not Found)`

Here is my route file :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/users', function(req, res) {
    var Users = require('../models/users'); // inkludiert das Users model
    var data; // undefined data variable

    Users.getData(function(err, result) { // ruft die getData Funktion vom Users Model auf
        // TODO: Error handling.
        data = result;
        render(data); // ruft die render Funktion auf und übergibt das Resultobjekt
    });

    function render(data){
      res.send(data);
    }
});

router.get('/api/users/add', function(req, res){
    console.log(req,res);
});

module.exports = router;
```

All I am trying to do is to call the `router.get('api/users/add'...` function in order to continue working with my api.

Now when I try to do that with my clientside javascript ajax call I get following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:3000/api/users/add. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

When I inspect the error it shows that the error occurs on my window.ajax call in the js file as well as in the callback function in my library.

Here is the necessary library code:

```
window.ajaxCall = {
  call: function(RequestType, pathToFile, data, cb){
    var ajax = null;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){ //Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Opera, Safari,...
        ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else if(window.ActiveXObject){ // Internet Explorer
        try{
            ajax = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0");
        } catch(e){
            try{
                ajax = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
            }
            catch(e){}
        }
    }
    if(ajax!=null){
      ajax.open(RequestType, pathToFile, true);
      typeof data == "string" || typeof data == "array" ? ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") : "" ;
      ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
          if(this.status == 200){
            cb(ajax.responseText);
          }
        }
      }
      ajax.send(data);
    }
  },
  abort: function(){
    ajax.abort();
  }
}
```

Comment: And protocols, domains and ports are the same? As in, is the website also running on localhost on port 3000 ?

Comment: And you seem to be missing the protocol `http://localhost` ?

Comment: Yes both are on :3000. What I don't understand is if I change my ajax call form localhost:3000/api/users/add to http://localhost:3000/api/users/add I get following error POST http://localhost:3000/api/users/add 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the protocol to your ajax call.

```
window.ajaxCall.call("POST", "http://localhost:3000/api/users/add", fd, function(responseText){
    // var response = JSON.parse(responseText);
    console.log(response);
});
```

Now, for the 404 part, your routes is expecting a get, but you are sending a post, change the router as follows:

```
router.post('/api/users/add', function(req, res){
    console.log(req,res);
});
```

Comment: Hello thank you for that input. I have updated my question with the result when I change the ajax call url.

Comment: Well, the 404 you get now is a different error, and it seems to mean that now your request is getting to your server but the server cannot resolve the route.

Comment: Yea I know - but shouldn't router.get('/api/users/add', catch the request on that url ?

Comment: no, it should not, check my edit. router is expecting a get, and you are sending a post.

Comment: oh shoot - I am using post in my ajax and listening for get. 
Unfortunately after changing it to your code i still get the same 404 ...